# RWD failing for large screen smartphones

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, responsive-design

These dog gone phone manufacturers are making our job harder. The introduction of larger phones is causing Bootstrap RWD to respond as a tablet instead of a phone. This is not a major deal sometimes because the responsiveness did take place but the dropdown menu (hamburger menu) fails to show up and forcing it to open prematurely it's not right either. Then you'll have the same problem with smaller tablets or phones in landscape mode.

Here is what I mean:

This is the way I designed it to look for `col-xs-12` and instead I am getting the `col-sm-12` to render in the phones as the image further below displays. "So what if the hamburger menu doesn't display", you'll say. The regular menu is still too small in a phone and hard to tap.

here is the code I am using for the header

```
    <header>
    <div class="header">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">

                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">MENU</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="images/banner.png" alt="banner" /></a>
                </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="navigation">
                        <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="about.php">about</a></li>
                        <li><a href="testimonials.php">testimonials</a></li>
                        <li><a href="services.php">services</a></li>                
                        <li><a href="contact.php">contact</a></li>    
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

Anyone knows how to get around this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The media queries are in bootstrap (which shouldn't be touched and altered with caution) But altering the media goes back to my problem of premature responsiveness.

Comment: Yes I know I can do. And I can do so that it looks great on my phone (Galaxy S5) but in my wife's iPhone 6Plus the website renders like a tablet. I would like to force it so that even with a large phone, it still outputs a phone display

Comment: That may be because the browser thinks it is a tablet. If I recall correctly, the i6+ has some different pixel ratio that is telling your browser that it is actually a bigger pixel amount than it actually is. According to [here](http://jsfiddle.net/x27u0e9y/) the pixel of iPhone6 is `750x1334` while the iPhone6 + is `1242x2208`. Your code is working correctly, your phone is telling your browser that it is 1242px wide.

Comment: Totally misread the problem. I'm probably wrong, gonna delete all my nonsense and find the truth.

Comment: That dies make sense Tim. I still can't find the justification for the Note 3. It is big but I din't think is big enough for it to break my bootstrap. But your explanation sounds good enough to get a nod from the client lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I found the problem folks. I feel like doing a face palm so please, I accept all the "duh" and "doi" you throw my way. lol Here is how to fix it.

Add `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` to the head and voila!

:shaking my head:

Comment: I just found exactly the same issue, so you're not alone. So "obvious" (in the way such things always are after the event) that I never thought to look for it.